# Combining files and HTML pages in the same document library

Tags: document, library, html

We need to have both ordinary files ( doc, pdf, xls) and HTML content that can be shown as popups in the same Document Library. Currently we have added a "Basic Page" content type to a regular Document Library, but this is not very elegant, as we also had to add a HTML column to the content type and use this to fill out the information. So the users create pages, then go back and edit the properties of the newly created ASPX file, and then enter the HTML content in this column. Our current setup is working, thanks to custom XSL, but there has to be a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would have considered maybe using a Wiki library, which stores all HTML content in the *WikiField*. Obviously, mixing the 2 is possible but not at all elegant. Use lookup columns to link documents to respective Wiki page, and load that in the popup.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Still having the Document Library as the base, what would be the best content type for having elements that hosts the lookups to the Wiki pages? 

This question is what led me to using the "Basic Page" content type in the first place, the closest thing to a blank content type that I could find, that would allow me to add a HTML content field as well as a "Description" and a people lookup column.